# Trouble using dup2 to make a C program execute a command such as 'ls /bin | grep grep | grep b'

Tags: c, piping, dup2

I'm having trouble using dup2 to make a c program execute a command such as `ls /bin | grep grep | grep b`. When I comment out the third command and associated pipe it executes `ls /bin | grep grep` fine, but with the last command it just returns right away. Also when I enter 'ps' the processes are still running. I think it's due to how I close the pipes.  My code is below:

```
int main()
{
    int pipeA[2];
    int pipeB[2];

    pipe(pipeA);
    pipe(pipeB);

    int pidA,pidB,pidC;

    if(pidA = fork())
    {
            close(pipeA[0]);
            dup2(pipeA[1],1);
            close(pipeA[1]);
            execlp("ls","ls","/bin",NULL);
            printf("error\n");
    }

    if(pidB = fork())
    {
            close(pipeA[1]);
            dup2(pipeA[0],0);
            close(pipeA[0]);

            close(pipeB[0]);
            dup2(pipeB[1],1);
            close(pipeB[1]);
            execlp("grep","grep","grep",NULL);
            printf("error\n");
    }

    if(pidC = fork())
    {
            close(pipeB[1]);
            dup2(pipeB[0],0);
            close(pipeB[0]);
            execlp("grep","grep","b",NULL);
            printf("error");
    }


    while(pidA != wait(0)){}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't closing enough file descriptors.

```
/* Semi-working code */
int main()
{
    int pipeA[2];
    int pipeB[2];

    pipe(pipeA);
    pipe(pipeB);

    int pidA,pidB,pidC;

    if (pidA = fork())
    {
            close(pipeB[0]);  // "ls" is not going to use the second pipe
            close(pipeB[1]);  // Ditto
            close(pipeA[0]);
            dup2(pipeA[1], 1);
            close(pipeA[1]);
            execlp("ls", "ls", "/bin", (char *)NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "error executing 'ls'\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    if (pidB = fork())
    {
            close(pipeA[1]);
            dup2(pipeA[0],0);
            close(pipeA[0]);
            close(pipeB[0]);
            dup2(pipeB[1],1);
            close(pipeB[1]);
            execlp("grep", "grep", "grep", (char *)NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "error execing 'grep grep'\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    if (pidC = fork())
    {
            close(pipeA[0]);  // The second grep is not going to use the first pipe
            close(pipeA[1]);  // Ditto
            close(pipeB[1]);
            dup2(pipeB[0],0);
            close(pipeB[0]);
            execlp("grep", "grep", "b", (char *)NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "error execing 'grep b'\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    close(pipeA[0]);  // The parent process is not using the pipes at all
    close(pipeA[1]);
    close(pipeB[0]);
    close(pipeB[1]);

    while (pidA != wait(0))
        ;

    return 0; 
}
```

Because you didn't close `pipeA` in the second `grep`, you end up with the first `grep` waiting for input from the pipe the second `grep` still has open, even though the process will not write to it.  Because of that, the first `grep` does not finish, so the second doesn't finish either - even though the `ls` does complete.  These comments would apply even if the parent process closed its copies of the pipes - as the corrected code does.

Notice how you end up closing all 4 descriptors returned by the two calls to `pipe()` in each of the four processes - three children and the parent process.

This leaves one residual problem - the process hierarchy is upside down because of your aconventional use of `if (pidA = fork())`.  You have a child process waiting for its parents.  You need to use:

```
if ((pidA = fork()) == 0)
{
    /* Be childish */
}
```

Similarly for each of the other two processes.  You should also check the `pipe()` calls and the `fork()` calls for failure, just to be sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void err_exit(const char *format, ...);

/* Working code */
int main(void)
{
    int pipeA[2];
    int pipeB[2];

    if (pipe(pipeA) != 0 || pipe(pipeB) != 0)
        err_exit("Failed to create a pipe\n");

    int pidA,pidB,pidC;

    if ((pidA = fork()) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to fork (A)\n");
    else if (pidA == 0)
    {
            close(pipeB[0]);  // "ls" is not going to use the second pipe
            close(pipeB[1]);  // Ditto
            close(pipeA[0]);
            dup2(pipeA[1], 1);
            close(pipeA[1]);
            execlp("ls", "ls", "/bin", (char *)NULL);
            err_exit("error executing 'ls'\n");
    }

    if ((pidB = fork()) < 0)
        err_exit("failed to fork (B)\n");
    else if (pidB == 0)
    {
            close(pipeA[1]);
            dup2(pipeA[0],0);
            close(pipeA[0]);
            close(pipeB[0]);
            dup2(pipeB[1],1);
            close(pipeB[1]);
            execlp("grep", "grep", "grep", (char *)NULL);
            err_exit("error execing 'grep grep'\n");
    }

    if ((pidC = fork()) < 0)
        err_exit("failed to fork (C)\n");
    else if (pidC == 0)
    {
            close(pipeA[0]);  // The second grep is not going to use the first pipe
            close(pipeA[1]);  // Ditto
            close(pipeB[1]);
            dup2(pipeB[0],0);
            close(pipeB[0]);
            execlp("grep", "grep", "b", (char *)NULL);
            err_exit("error execing 'grep b'\n");
    }

    close(pipeA[0]);  // The parent process is not using the pipes at all
    close(pipeA[1]);
    close(pipeB[0]);
    close(pipeB[1]);

    while (wait(0) != -1)
        ;

    printf("Continuing here...\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("That's enough of that!\n");

    return 0; 
}

static void err_exit(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(1);
}
```

When doctored to use `/usr/bin` instead of `/bin`, this program works OK on Mac OS X 10.7.3.  It lists three files and then generates the message about 'Continuing here':

```
bzegrep
bzfgrep
bzgrep
Continuing here...
That's enough of that!
```

Comment: thanks for the help I just saw your answer to another question and edited mine before i saw you answer this

Comment: i'm having another small problem i'd like my program to continue after the pipe (i'm writing a simple shell), but the piping seems always end the program even though none of the execlps are replacing the parent program right?

Comment: You'd need to place the code in the `main()` function inside a function of some sort (other than `main()`) and then call it, and go back to whatever else you want to happen next. ... **Oops!** There was a line missing in the 'working' code; it was the `else if (pidC == 0)` line now added.  I also added some debugging code at the end, to indicate where the main program continues after the pipeline completes.  I also changed the condition in the `wait()` loop.